# button is not showing image

Tags: css, image, class, button, extjs

I use 3 buttons in my extjs script. Strange thing is that i don't see them. If i use firebug to inspect the element i see this

```
<button id="button-1051-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" autocomplete="off" role="button" hidefocus="true" type="button">
<span id="button-1051-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner" style="">&nbsp;</span>
<span id="button-1051-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon" style="background-image: url("../resources/themes/images/default/grid/page-prev.gif");">&nbsp;</span>
</button>
```

That is the correct gif file and it is on the server. Is this something to do with overflow?

I hope you can help

Comment: first you should check path if is right

Comment: We can't see the css for x-btn-icon. Does it have a height and width set? Also is it set to display block?

Comment: Please, add to your question the css for classes x-btn-center, x-btn-inner and x-btn-icon. What version of ExtJS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [this example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/form/custom-form.html) you should use x-btn-icon and x-tbar-page-next css classes together in order to show a "Next Page" button image. I suggest you to override x-tbar-page-next css class to use a customized image.

Quick reference to the important part of [the example's](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/form/custom-form.html) "Next Page" button:

```
<button id="button-1020-btnEl" type="button" class="x-btn-center" hidefocus="true" role="button" autocomplete="off" data-qtip="Next Page" style="height: 16px; ">
    <span id="button-1020-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner" style="">&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="button-1020-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon x-tbar-page-next" style=""></span>
</button>
```